Sorting entries in a GTK dropdown
Objective: display the items in a dropdown in alphabetical order.
I have a dropdown whose model is a GtkStringList. I believe I need to define a GtkStringSorter and apply it to the model, but I'm not sure how to proceed. The following lines compile but a) do not produce a sorted dropdown and b) produce a runtime error.
const char *strings[4] = {"Larry","Moe","Curly",NULL};
GtkStringList *stringlist = gtk_string_list_new (strings);
GtkWidget *dropdown= gtk_drop_down_new(G_LIST_MODEL(stringlist), NULL);

/* Not sure how to code the following lines */
GtkStringSorter *string_sorter = gtk_string_sorter_new (NULL);
GtkSortListModel *sort_list_model = gtk_sort_list_model_new (G_LIST_MODEL(stringlist), GTK_SORTER(string_sorter));

gtk_drop_down_set_model ( GTK_DROP_DOWN( dropdown), G_LIST_MODEL(sort_list_model));

What am I missing?
TIA.

"b) produce a runtime error." ... and we are supposed to guess what that error might be?

On opening the dropdown, I get g_list_model_get_n_items: assertion 'G_IS_LIST_MODEL (list)' failed and also Segmentation fault.

@9-Pin That information should be in the question along with a [mre].

I reviewed the code samples mentioned by @Holger, and based on them used the approach of appending string objects to a list store.
Comparison function
gint comparestrings (gconstpointer a, gconstpointer b, gpointer user_data) {
GtkStringObject *object_a = (GtkStringObject *)a;
GtkStringObject *object_b = (GtkStringObject *)b;
const char *string_a = gtk_string_object_get_string(object_a);
const char *string_b = gtk_string_object_get_string(object_b);
return g_ascii_strncasecmp (string_a, string_b, 10);
}

Instantiating the dropdown and populating with string objects
GListStore *list_store = g_list_store_new(GTK_TYPE_STRING_OBJECT);
GtkWidget *dropdown= gtk_drop_down_new(G_LIST_MODEL(list_store), NULL);
g_list_store_append(list_store,gtk_string_object_new("zebra"));
g_list_store_append(list_store,gtk_string_object_new("horse"));
g_list_store_append(list_store,gtk_string_object_new("monkey"));
g_list_store_append(list_store,gtk_string_object_new("aardvark"));
g_list_store_sort (list_store, comparestrings, NULL);

Sorts correctly as advertised.


There are several examples of sorting strings here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77619798/22768315
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78185115/22768315
At least they show the principle of how it could work.
There is an even simpler solution :-).

#include"dropdown-sort.h"


void activate (GtkApplication *app, gpointer data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window =gtk_application_window_new(app);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(window,50,50);


 const char *strings[4] = {"Larry","Moe","Curly",NULL};
 GtkStringList *stringlist = gtk_string_list_new (strings);

  /*you have to implement the GtkExpression  */
  GtkExpression *expression = gtk_property_expression_new(GTK_TYPE_STRING_OBJECT,NULL,"string");
  GtkStringSorter *string_sorter = gtk_string_sorter_new (expression);

  GtkSortListModel *sort_list_model = gtk_sort_list_model_new (G_LIST_MODEL(stringlist), GTK_SORTER(string_sorter));

  GtkWidget *dropdown= gtk_drop_down_new(G_LIST_MODEL(sort_list_model), NULL);
  GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL,10);
  gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box),dropdown);
  gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window),box);

 gtk_widget_set_visible(window,TRUE);
}


Have fun programming.

Thanks for this. I was hoping to avoid creating a custom class for only strings, but perhaps that is the way forward. Will advise.

I'm sorry, but I had to explore it myself. :-)
