Populating a drop down from a GtklistStore in GTK4
I have a GtkListStore, and I want to populate a dropdown from its contents. Is this possible? I've tried something like this:
widgets->log_entries[entry_index] = gtk_drop_down_new(G_LIST_MODEL(widgets->station_list_store), NULL);

widgets->station_list_store is a GtkListStore.
This didn't work, as I don't see any items from my list.

Unfortunately, the surrounding program code is missing here to give an exact answer.
However, there are a whole range of questions and answers on the problem "dropdown".
https://stackoverflow.com/a/79037245/22768315
GTK 4 drop down signal "activate" not working
https://stackoverflow.com/a/79225876/22768315
In addition, there are also examples of how to create a list store:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78291720/22768315
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77619798/22768315
Maybe that can help. Otherwise, please provide a meaningful script.
Have fun programming.
